# Why is poisson formula in excel not working in java?

Tags: java, excel, vba, excel-formula, apache-poi

I have an excel file which has a formula using POISSON. It is working fine in excel, but we have a java program which read the values in excel file using apache POI. any reason why the formula is not working?

Comment: Your claim is wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `apache poi 4.0.1` `POISSON` function is working well used as `Excel` formula.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelFormula {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 
   sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(2);
   sheet.createRow(1).createCell(0).setCellValue(5);
   sheet.createRow(2).createCell(0).setCellFormula("POISSON(A1,A2,TRUE)");

   FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
   DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);

   String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0), formulaEvaluator);
   System.out.println(cellValue);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }
 }
}
```

This prints

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ javac -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* CreateExcelFormula.java 
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* CreateExcelFormula 
0.1246520195
```

And the resulting `Excel.xlsx` contains the formula `=POISSON(A1,A2,TRUE)` in cell `A3`.

Comment: I have this problem the example is:
=POISSON(0,-0.19,FALSE)
in excel the value would be 1.2092
but in POI java the value is !#NUM

Comment: @rlchaps26: The formula `=POISSON(0,-0.19,FALSE) ` results in `!#NUM` in `Excel` too. See [POISSON function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/poisson-function-d81f7294-9d7c-4f75-bc23-80aa8624173a): "If mean < 0, POISSON returns the #NUM! error value.".

Comment: Yes I already read that.. But you try using Excel 2013.. or Online excel. The result value will be 1.2092

Comment: @rlchaps26: `Excel 2007` returns `!#NUM` as documented. So in `Excel 2013` `Microsoft` violates it's own function descriptions. So what shall other software which tries following those rules do then?

Comment: Yes, that would be the question. So, I am assuming POI is not updated with Microsoft Excel changes.

Comment: I would call this change a bug in later `Excel` versions. Or why is `=POISSON(0,-0.19,FALSE)` resulting in `1.209249598` but `=POISSON(1,-0.19,FALSE)` is `#NUM!` and not `-0.229757424` in `Excel` versions after 2007?